# how to hide button on specific user in openerp?

Tags: odoo, access-rights

I am working on python, xml in openerp. I am creating access right for manager and user. I want to hide "Convert to opportunity" button on user login. And show that button in manager login. how to hide this button on login user.

see the following screenshot.

[image]

I created groups for manager and user separately.

```
<button string="Convert to Opportunity" type="action" states="draft,open,pending" help="Convert to Opportunity" class="oe_highlight" position="replace"/>
```

while i am adding this code. "Convert to Opportunity" button will be hidden. But it is hidden user and manager.

Then i tried add "groups" attribute and place my groups name. but it will give architecture 
error

```
<button string="Convert to Opportunity" type="action" states="draft,open,pending" help="Convert to Opportunity" class="oe_highlight" group="User" position="replace"/>
```

what did i mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of the attribute is "groups" with s not "group".

And you have to give it group ids (xml-ids) instead of simple names.

Througout the OpenERP Code you will find many examples for this, just search for "groups=" in xml files.

some examples for group ids:

- base.group_sale_manager - base module for users with access right "manager" in sale
- base.group_user - base module for basic users
- and so on

if you want already installed/created groups and their ids go into your database and look into the table ir_model_data (filter by model='res.groups'). the column "name" in that table is the xml-id you need.

Comment: how to go my database. i am using teriminal

Comment: if you're using postgresql db use psql in terminal or get pgadmin3 ;-)

Comment: i used following process in teriminal "sudo su postgres[enter]-->psql my_database_name[enter]--->" it is showing "my_database_name#" then wht do i do? how see that table and Group name(xml id)

Comment: _man psql_ will help a lot i guess :-P

just enter some querys, for example: 

`select * from ir_model_data where model = 'res.groups';`

but i prefer pgadmin3

Comment: Thank u, i got answer in this way.

Answer (score 0):

in odoo 10, it should be:

```
groups="sales_team.group_sale_manager"
```